# Output buffering issue - PHP

Tags: php

```
ob_start();

for($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) {     
  echo $i, ' '; 
  ob_flush(); 
  flush(); 
  sleep(1); 
}
```

Expected: `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9` appearing incrementally every second in the browser.

Result: `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9` at once AFTER ten seconds.

I just couldn't get output buffering to work.

Comment: Works for me.  Are you using it through an httpd that may be buffering the output?

Comment: depends on browser behavior, using compression etc. Check it in CLI.

Answer (score 0):

I believe its a bug in a particular version of PHP, solution can be found here...

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php#85383

Answer (score 0):

I am having the exact same problem, which does not seem to be a bug in PHP, just a problem with the browsers these days. (Though it MAY be some compression option in the Web Server)
As stated in [this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php#109699), it seems that browsers have now taken an all-or-nothing approach to output buffering.